# Google spreadsheet showing undefined values when submitting through an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-sheets

I'm trying to send the data I gathered from my web app to a google spreadsheet.
I'm using the script from Martin Hawksey:
https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/1276293

I've set it up and did everything as shown in the manual. And I am getting data back, but it's showing up as undefined values:
[image: image of spreadsheet]

This is the code I use to send the JSON string to my spreadsheet:

```
    function sendData(){
    var url = 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby3SUJvfEjdHWVoEON0L5hN4uXod8M4Jv1LAIWH3Ny16MIUz9o/exec';
    var data = JSON.stringify(member);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("succes! I sent this: " + data);
            console.log("got this back: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        },
    });
}
```

This gives me a success message, it even tells me which row it was placed on.
This is the JSON string I'm sending:

```
{"Voornaam":"Name","Achternaam":"Name","Mail":"x@x.com","Verjaardag":"0/0/0000","Foto":"https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxx/picture?width=1020","School":"School X","Richting":"Course X"}
```

I even checked this JSON with a JSON parser online and it didn't return any errors.

For starters, I'm not entirely sure how to check which string I'm receiving at my spreadsheet. If it's still correct when it arrives. I tried logging it, but can't seem to get any response from the google logger.

If anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong, you would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You stringfy the JSON before you send it to your web Script. But the web script is expecting a JSON object, hence unable to retrieve the data. I would remove the stringify function and send the JSON as is.

Comment: That did the trick, works perfectly now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web script expects a JSON object. However, Ajax call is made with a string using the stringify function

```
var data = JSON.stringify(member);
```

Modifying the script to make the GET call with JSON object as is resolved the issue, like so

```
var data = member;
```